# Objective-C equivalent of "override" in C#

Tags: objective-c

Assume a class Vehicle has a method called "StartEngine", and in my subclass called "Airplane" I want to override "StartEngine". If I use C#, I should use the "override" keyword in Airplane's StartEngine method declaration/definition.

The reason I am asking, is that if instead of "StartEngine" I type "startengine",  C# will complain, but Objective-C won't, thanks to that keyword.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All class and instance methods in Objective-C are dispatched dynamically and can be overridden in subclasses.  There is nothing like C#'s `override` keyword, or like its `virtual` keyword.

Comment: That makes sense.. I've just learned what a method is in objective-c : a pointer to the actual function a name and an encoding... Nothing extra.

Comment: All methods in Objective-C are polymorphic, including class methods. (This is unlike "static" methods in C#, Java, and C++, which are not polymorphic.)

Comment: Let me clarify: All methods in Objective-C are polymorphic in the sense that they can always be overridden by subclasses.  No methods in Objective-C are polymorphic on argument type.

Comment: Now in the post-Swift World we definitely have more keywords like `nullable`... no developments on this front in the last 2 years, right?

Comment: Correct, there have been no changes to Objective-C on this front.

Comment: One major use of an 'override' annotation is to prevent subtle bugs when the base class implementation gets renamed.  You can have subclasses out there still thinking they are overriding something when in fact they are no longer being called by by anyone.  So I wish ObjC would add something along these lines.  The compiler detects that Class X has no selector Y in many cases, so it should be able to detect that Class X claims to override selector Y but XBase has no selector Y.

Answer (score 12):

Yep - it's definitely possible. There's no override keyword though. Just declare a function with an identical signature in your subclass, and it will be called instead of the superclasses version.

Here's what Airplane's startEngine method might look like:

```
- (void)startEngine
{
    // custom code

    // call through to parent class implementation, if you want
    [super startEngine];
}
```

Comment: I've just clarified the question. I know overriding is possible in objective-c, I just want the compiler to check I'm actually overriding a method, and not creating a new one in the subclass.

Comment: Ahh - I see. Unfortunately, the Objective-C compiler doesn't provide any way to do that. Heck - even calling a function that doesn't exist is only a warning! :-) I think your best bet in that case would be to make the abstract base class' method implementations throw NSExceptions.

Answer (score 2):

All methods in Objective-C are overrideable, you just write a method for the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far are missing the actual point of the question. It wasn't "can I override methods" it was "can I get the compiler to tell me when something I think is an override actually is not overriding anything".

Sadly, the answer to the question is no. At the time of this writing, ObjC doesn't have any way to annotate a method as being an explicit override of a base class method.

Because of dynamic dispatch, it isn't possible to have an exact equivalent to what C#, C++, and Java have. Dynamic dispatch means that essentially all objects respond to all messages, just sometimes that response is to throw an exception. And how any particular message is responded to can be changed dynamically at runtime.  So a compiler cannot tell you at compile time with 100% certainty whether any particular method will have a non-default handler at runtime.

Now that said, I've never written an ObjC compiler, but in theory I believe it would be possible for the compiler to check the method you are declaring as an override against the *statically* declared method signatures in all the base classes. This is how the vast majority of ObjC code is written, with method signatures explicitly, statically written out in @interface declarations. So you could have an annotation like NS_INTERFACE_OVERRIDE that requires some base class of the current class have the same signature explicitly declared in its @interface section.