# Objective-C convention for overridden methods

Tags: objective-c, oop, overriding

In Java, when you override a method, you are advised (almost forced) to add the `@Override` annotation. Is there a convention to mark (either in comments, or by some other mechanism) overridden methods in the Objective-C world?

Comment: Related question: [Objective-C equivalent of override in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034554/objective-c-equivalent-of-override-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. All methods in Objective-C are sent via Objective-C's messaging, so all methods can be overridden. That's part of the language.

There's no convention for marking this, either. It's part of the language that it happens, and if you were to comment otherwise it'd just be confusing when you did it later, accidentally or intentionally.

Comment: I am aware of that, the situation is the same with Java - (almost) all functions are virtual, however I still see the point to warn that you are overriding a parent method. It will certainly make errors like not calling `[super loadView];` easier to spot

Comment: You need to check the documentation and read your method. Some methods, it's important to call super. Some methods, it's critical that you **don't** call super. In the past, I'd have said what you want isn't possible for the IDE, but it's apparent Apple can do almost anything now that they control the compiler, framework and language, so it might be worth filing a suggestion via their bug reporter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Xcode does this, but the AppCode IDE from Jetbrains automatically annotates overridden methods with the little blue ***override badge*** in the margin, like so:

[image: AppCode Override]

. . further to that (also shown), I also like to create some live templates (aka code-snippets in Xcode) to annotate overridden methods with a #pragma tag. I find that it helps to define a standard structure in this order:

- class methods
- initialization & destruction
- public methods / protocol methods
- overridden methods
- private methods

and by having Live Templates/Code Snippets I can just type 'override [tab]' and the IDE will create the #pragma tag for me.

. . perhaps you could even use OCLint to check that this structure is adhered to.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

It doesn't seem to matter as much, probably because of the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: The fact that ObjC uses dynamic dispatch is irrelevant to the utility.  It may be relevant to how *difficult* it is to implement a compile time check, but it would certainly be useful in ObjC if it existed. The main utility of compiler-checked overrides is noticing when the base class method gets refactored/renamed. Your subclass may *think* it's still overriding something but that something got renamed, and now no one is calling your method.

Comment: @Baxissimo The fact is that there is no such annotation and, in Objective-C, such an annotation would be questionable because *all* objects respond to *all* selectors. It's just that sometimes the response is to throw an exception. It's a mistake to think of sending a message to an Objective-C object as being the same as calling a function on a Swift object.

Comment: I found this question after wasting time trying to figure out why a test started failing. The fake in the test was trying to override a method in the base class, but the base method got renamed.  An override annotation would have caught this.  It wouldn't be a panacea, since as you say, a base class can dynamically handle any method it wants to in a way that's impossible to determine statically.  However, most typical ObjC code *does* use static method signatures declared in headers, and you could have an annotation that means "must be an override of statically declared method".

Comment: @Baxissimo Why did you waste time trying to figure out why the test was failing? The exception thrown in the test would be obvious. There's a reason why Apple never added the `override` annotation to Objective-C and instead created a whole new language.